# How to remove a 5 dynamic textboxes in a row by pressing the button delete

Tags: c#

Have this add button that will create and generate 5 dynamic textbox in a single click
now. what i want is that i want also to remove them in a single click.

Here is The Code to generate textbox.

```
new int Top = 459;
new int Left = 619;
Stack<TextBox> textboxes = new Stack<TextBox>();
List<String> controlNames = new List<String>();

private void button17_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textadd1 = new TextBox();
    this.Controls.Add(textadd1);
    textadd1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
    textadd1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
    textadd1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(Left, Top);
    textadd1.Name = "textBox1" + controlNames.Count;
    textadd1.BringToFront();
    textadd1.Size = new Size(376, 24);
    textadd1.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
    textadd1.Text = "";
    textboxes.Push(textadd1);
    controlNames.Add(textadd1.Name);

    TextBox textadd2 = new TextBox();
    this.Controls.Add(textadd2);
    textadd2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
    textadd2.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
    textadd2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
    textadd2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(998, Top);
    textadd2.Name = "textBox2" + controlNames.Count;
    textadd2.BringToFront();
    textadd2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(56, 12);
    textadd2.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
    textboxes.Push(textadd2);
    controlNames.Add(textadd2.Name);

    TextBox textadd3 = new TextBox();
    this.Controls.Add(textadd3);
    textadd3.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
    textadd3.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
    textadd3.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
    textadd3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1056, Top);
    textadd3.Name = "textBox3" + controlNames.Count;
    textadd3.Name = "textBox3" + controlCounts;
    textadd3.BringToFront();
    textadd3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(64, 24);
    textadd3.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
    textadd3.Text = "";
    textadd3.TextChanged += textBox3_TextChanged;
    textboxes.Push(textadd3);
    controlNames.Add(textadd3.Name);

    TextBox textadd4 = new TextBox();
    this.Controls.Add(textadd4);
    textadd3.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
    textadd4.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
    textadd4.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
    textadd4.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1122, Top);
    textadd4.Name = "textBox4" + controlNames.Count;
    textadd4.Name = "textBox4" + controlCounts;
    textadd4.BringToFront();
    textadd4.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(50, 24);
    textadd4.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
    textadd4.Text = "";
    textadd4.TextChanged += textBox4_TextChanged;
    textboxes.Push(textadd4);
    controlNames.Add(textadd4.Name);

    TextBox textadd5 = new TextBox();
    this.Controls.Add(textadd5);
    textadd5.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
    textadd5.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
    textadd5.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
    textadd5.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1174, Top);
    textadd5.Name = "textBox5" + controlNames.Count;
    textadd5.Name = "textBox5" + controlCounts;
    textadd5.BringToFront();
    textadd5.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(108, 24);
    textadd5.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
    textadd5.Text = "";
    textboxes.Push(textadd5);
    controlNames.Add(textadd5.Name);

    Top += 22;
}
```

and Here is the Code i Use to delete Textbox the only problem is that it will delete only 1 textbox not all 5.

```
public void RemoveLast()
{
    foreach (TextBox t in textboxes)
    {
        if (t is TextBox)
        {
            this.Controls.Remove(t);
            t.Dispose();
            return;
        }
}
```

and i try this code also it will delete all textbox. but if the user click the add button 5times it will generate 5 row of textbox. it will work but after pressing the delete it will delete all rows not 1 at a time. i need it to be 1 at a time. if the user click it. that is why i leave it // to be check

```
foreach (TextBox t in textboxes)
{
   this.Controls.Remove(t);
   t.Dispose();
}       

//Remove void to execute
private void remove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RemoveLast();
}
```

Comment: Edit your question with `indentation` properly.

Comment: sorry im just new here. i try it thank you

Comment: *button17_Click* - please rename your controls after you drop them on a form. It costs nothing and pays immensely in making code readable. If Microsoft took the same approach to naming things in .net we wouldn't have eg `this.Controls.Remove` we'd have `this.Collection27.Method41` and no one would want to read/code C#

Comment: my bad. ill change it.

Answer (score 1):

Do something like:

```
public void RemoveLastRowOf5()
{
    for(int i=1; i<=5 && textboxes.Count>0; i++) {
        textboxes.Pop().Dispose();
    }
}
```

> may i know after i save it in the database. how to clear the dynamic
> textboxes user input?

This is a disadvantage to using the `Stack`. You'd have to pop everything into another structure, clearing as you go, then put them back in the stack. If you used a List instead, you could access it like a Stack but also be able to iterate over the contents without removing them.

Here's an example of clearing:

```
public void ClearAll()
{
    Stack<TextBox> temp = new Stack<TextBox>();
    while(textboxes.Count>0) {
        TextBox tb = textboxes.Pop();
        tb.Clear();
        temp.Push(tb);
    }
    while(temp.Count>0) {
        textboxes.Push(temp.Pop());
    }
}
```

There are other ways to do this.

Comment: Yeah This get the result. thanks .Pop is the key and your for loop analyzation is amazing,.  by the way would you know how to restart it in original space after i delete it will add in the space was remove .

Comment: Do the opposite of adding 22? `Top -= 22;`

Comment: Top 22 is the position i use to give space in the next textbox being add in the form

Comment: may i know after i save it in the database. how to clear the dynamic textboxes user input?

Answer (score 0):

well you return from you delete function after only doing one delete

```
        public void RemoveLast()
        {
            foreach (TextBox t in textboxes)
            {
                if (t is TextBox)

                {
                    this.Controls.Remove(t);
                    t.Dispose();
                    return; <<<<<<<======================
            

                }
           }
```

I think you mean

```
        public void RemoveLast()
        {
            foreach (TextBox t in textboxes)
            {
                if (t is TextBox)

                {
                    this.Controls.Remove(t);
                    t.Dispose();
                
                }
         }
```

Comment: This will remove all the textboxes

Comment: Yeah i use the return value before but the same result. thanks by the way sir.

Comment: Hi since i posted this  can i ask how can i clear the textboxes after save in the database

Answer (score 0):

```
public void RemoveLast()
{
    int count = 0;  

    while (textboxes.Count > 0 && count < 5) // the count of TextBox that you want to delete
    {
        TextBox tb = textboxes.Pop();
        this.Controls.Remove(tb);
        
        tb.Dispose();
        count++;  // my mistake.. I modified.
    }
}
```

I think you want to do this.

Comment: How does `count` come into play here? It stays at `0` the whole time...

Comment: This will remove all the textboxes

Comment: I'm sorry. It was my mistake...

Comment: it will remove all textboxes not per row. brother.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).